# Reduce length of right side of border

Tags: css

I have a border  :

```
.verticalLineTop {
    border-top:solid #6E6A6B;
    border-width:1px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

I am hardcoding the width in order to trim part of the right of the border, can this be done using css ?

So instead of :

```
________________________
```

This is displayed :

```
____________________
```

Comment: Not possible. You'll have to work around it (eg. using an absolutely positioned element that mimics the border)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set a partial CSS `border-top`, its all or nothing.

If you always want the top border to be a certain percentage of the width, you could nest an element with a percentage width.

```
.verticalLineTop
{
    width:80%;
    border-top:solid 1px #000;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/P3RKB/1*

Answer (score 1):

```
.verticalLineTop:before
 {
   width:80%;
   border-top:solid 1px #000;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   padding-top: 10px;
 }
```